# stylesheet not working in chrome , working fine in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problem with css style sheet, its not working properly in chrome but working fine in firefox

> www.danafoods.ae

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.danafoods.ae/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: @LaljiTadhani its not a php issue(i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is lot of parsing errors in your CSS file (http://www.danafoods.ae/wp-content/themes/wpnation/style.css).

For Chrome, it may look that some of { } braces are left unclosed. See the validation results, it should help you to fix errors:

[The W3C CSS Validation Service - CSS validation results](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.danafoods.ae%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fwpnation%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to first see why it can't find the missing wp-admin/admin-ajax.php that it's warning about - if you're trying to fetch css files through ajax, that might be preventing it. Two things I'd try, have you tried running your site locally and seeing if it works in chrome on localhost? And also, have you got the correct permissions on those files/folders?